# Visual Studio 2010 disappears after installing Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, installation

First I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional, then I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

How to run Visual Studio 2010?

In Visual Studio 2013 - No problem.

But in Visual Studio 2010 - Visual Studio 2010 disappears.

Comment: You should install **VS2010** first - then **VS2013**

Answer (score 0):

The older version must be installed first, since the installation does not downgrade.
First install the 2010 version and then to 2013.